# How to set columns width of smart table with annotations?

Tags: sapui5

I have a smart table and displaying the columns through the annotations.
However the number of columns is more, and the content is getting overlapped in the row.

Is it possible to control the width of these columns through annotations?

Comment: IMHO, It's not possible and should not be.

Comment: This would be a contradiction to the responsiveness that the control aims for. Instead you can annotate the importance of each column and depending on the available space, they will then be hidden or displayed. It can also wrap content by putting the content into one overflow cell of the row.

Answer (score 0):

Change the `tableType="Table"` in smart table configuration. It will solve the overlapping problem.